# Prompt user for source and destination folder by referencing a range of cells - involves data transfer

Tags: excel, vba

I have 4 columns of data that I need to be transformed into a list of folders and sub folders. Column B will be the first list of primary folders, and each entry of column C will be a sub-folder and deeper into sub folder of column D in the corresponding folder from column B.

Column A comprises of .pdf files names stored in the source destinations that needs to be transferred into the last sub-folder of the target destination.

Present Source & target Directory:

```
Source: C:\Users\Manzurfa\Desktop\Macro Project\Carlo Project\Order Confirmations
Target: C:\Users\Manzurfa\Desktop\Macros
```

While the below code works exceptionally well, I would need the macro to prompt the user to specify the Source folder and target folder, instead of hard-forcing the directories.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Tester()    

'Const SRC_FOLDER = "C:\Users\Manzurfa\Desktop\Macro Project\Carlo Project\Order Confirmations\"
'Const DEST_FOLDER = "C:\Users\Manzurfa\Desktop\Macros\"

Dim Rng As Range, fPath, fName
Dim SRC_FOLDER As String, DEST_FOLDER As String
Dim maxRows As Long, maxCols As Long, r As Long, c As Long

Set Rng = Selection
maxRows = Rng.Rows.Count
maxCols = Rng.Columns.Count

With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
.Show
If .SelectedItems.Count = 1 Then
SRC_FOLDER = .SelectedItems(1)
End If
End With

If SRC_FOLDER <> "" Then
Open SRC_FOLDER For Output As #n
End If

'assuming the first row in ther selection is the headers...
'  otherwise, start at 1
For r = 2 To maxRows
    fPath = DEST_FOLDER '<<set starting point
    For c = 2 To maxCols
        fPath = fPath & "\" & Rng.Cells(r, c) '<<build next level
        If Len(Dir(fPath, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then MkDir fPath
 On Error Resume Next
    Next c
    'create file name
    fName = Right("0000000000" & Rng.Cells(r, 1).Value, 10) & ".pdf"
    'copy to fpath
    FileCopy SRC_FOLDER & fName, fPath & "\" & fName
Next r

  With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
  .Show
  If .SelectedItems.Count = 1 Then
  DEST_FOLDER = .SelectedItems(1)
  End If
  End With

  If DEST_FOLDER <> "" Then
  Open DEST_FOLDER For Output As #n
  End If

  End Sub
```

Any help on this would be duly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
Dim SRC_FOLDER As String, DEST_FOLDER as String

With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
.Show
If .SelectedItems.Count = 1 Then
    SRC_FOLDER = .SelectedItems(1)
End If
End With

If SRC_FOLDER<> "" Then
    Open SRC_FOLDER For Output As #n
End If
```

That's just for the SRC_FOLDER - you can change and update for Destination

Comment: Appreciate the super fast response @Badja. I've updated the body of the code that I previously attached (above), based off your instructions. Do you think that's right?

Comment: Fix the line below ` If DEST_FOLDER <> "" Then` - give this a try and see what happens = `F8` Through the Sub

Comment: Also, vba throws an warning on the line **Open SRC_FOLDER For Output As #n**

Error:
Compile Error - "Variable not defined" highlighting "#n"

Comment: @BADGA. You Sir! Are a genius. This Worked perfectly. One last question, the Vba is prompting me to select the files instead of the folder!. Do you think I should change this line ** msoFileDialogOpen** to something else that's restricted to selecting a Folder?

Comment: Try `With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)`

Answer (score 2):

This uses the `Application.FileDialog` method, and will loop until a valid selection is chosen, prompting the user if they press cancel on the dialog box to retry.

Also, Setting the `InitialFileName` will select a starting folder.

```
Dim sourcePath As String
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .Title = "Source Directory"
    .InitialFileName = "C:\Users\"
    Do
        If .Show = -1 And .SelectedItems.Count > 0 Then
            sourcePath = .SelectedItems(1)
            Exit Do
        Else
            Select Case MsgBox("Please select a source directory!", vbAbortRetryIgnore + vbDefaultButton2)
            Case vbAbort
                Exit Sub
            Case vbIgnore
                Exit Do
            End Select
        End If
    Loop
End With

' . . . . 

Dim targetPath As String
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .Title = "Target Directory"
    .InitialFileName = "C:\Users\"
    Do
        If .Show = -1 And .SelectedItems.Count > 0 Then
            targetPath = .SelectedItems(1)
            Exit Do
        Else
            Select Case MsgBox("Please select a source directory!", vbAbortRetryIgnore + vbDefaultButton2)
            Case vbAbort
                Exit Sub
            Case vbIgnore
                Exit Do
            End Select
        End If
    Loop
End With
```

Pressing 'OK' on the dialog box returns a value of `-1`, which is where the `If .Show = -1` comes from.

---

Since you are using two dialogs here (one for a source and one for a target), I would suggest that you turn this into a function instead:

```
Function promptFolderDlg(Optional sTitle As String = "Select folder path") As String

    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Title = sTitle
        .InitialFileName = "C:\Users\"
        Do
            If .Show = -1 And .SelectedItems.Count > 0 Then
                promptFolderDlg = .SelectedItems(1)
                Exit Function
            Else
                Select Case MsgBox("Please select a folder path!", vbAbortRetryIgnore + vbDefaultButton2)
                Case vbAbort
                    End
                Case vbIgnore
                    Exit Function
                End Select
            End If
        Loop
    End With

End Function
```

To use the above function, you would do something like this:

```
SRC_FOLDER = promptFolderDlg("Source Directory")

' . . .

fPath = promptFolderDlg("Target Directory")
```

Comment: This is a very good answer. Gives a lot more depth and insight on my answer. Wish I had the time to make new solutions, rather than fixing the users' own. `.AllowMultiSelect` flew over my head too

Comment: Thanks. `.AllowMultiSelect` is `False` by default, and therefore it's not required. I tend to be explicit with a lot defaults by habit, but you are okay to leave it off. :-)

Comment: @K.Dᴀᴠɪs, thank you for the insights. I was curious to understand the functionality of your code. Would you be able to help out with this error?
Compile Error: Sub or function not defined "promptFolderDlg"

Comment: @fahadmanzur Make sure you copy the function (the second code block I provided) into your module. It is a function, so it needs to be located out of your `Sub Tester() ... End Sub`.

Comment: Wow! It actually worked! You guys have done me a huge favor. This could be a major factor with my promotion. Thank you so much.